Error installing gnuplot 6.0.1 on Debian Bullseye
Trying to install gnuplot 6.0.1 on an NUC 5 running Raspian Desktop Bullseye and it throws this error:
qtterminal/qt_term.cpp:51:10: fatal error: QtCore: No such file or directory
   51 | #include <QtCore>
      |          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [Makefile:1044: qtterminal/qt_term.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/house/Downloads/GNUplot/gnuplot-6.0.1/src'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:1087: check-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/house/Downloads/GNUplot/gnuplot-6.0.1/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1238: check] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/house/Downloads/GNUplot/gnuplot-6.0.1/src'
make: *** [Makefile:427: check-recursive] Error 1

How to resolve it?

Some information here on the SourceFourge thread:
SourceForge thread
As per Dan H.'s reply to Peter R.'s suggestion:
apt install libqt5*dev qttools5-dev-tools
./configure --with-qt=qt5
make

solves the issue.
